# bootstrap error in the code?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to getting image from the popup, my query is ok but the image cannot be displayed in the popup. i give the id of the image but the id is not getting it. my code is ok but my result is not showing.

**my code**

this is the code where i used to try to shoing my image in the popup

```
<div align="center" style="margin-top:20px; color:#0F0;font-size:24px;"></div>
<div align="center" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <table border="2">
        <?php 
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
                <!-- Large modal -->
                <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <div id="form" class="modal-content">
                            <!-- <img src="<?php\ echo $row['img_name']?> "width=400px; height=400px;/> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <tr>
                <td width="100">
                    <a href="image.php?q=<?php echo $row['img_id'] ?>">DEL</a>
                    ||
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" onclick='update(id)'>view</button>
            </tr> 
        <?php } ?>
    </table>

    <script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function update(str) {
                $.get('image.php?q='+str,                           
                    function (data){
                        $("#form").html(data);
                    });
                }

                function showUser(str) {
                    if (str == "") {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                        return;
                    } 

                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    else { // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }

                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("dialog").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            $("#dialog").dialog();
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "image.php?q=" + str, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
        </script>
```

there is also jQuery in which i getting the image id and send to the other page and there i m seeing my image

**image.php**

```
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['q']))
            $id = $_GET['q'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT img_name FROM image WHERE img_id = $id");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $row['img_name']?>"width=280px; height=300px;/>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your HTML, missing closing tags and a div inside a table which is incorrect. I'd suggest you look at those first.

Comment: what are you trying to do are you taking this to same page or another